# Не работает ссылка HTML (не кликается)

Tags: html

При клике левой кнопкой мыши на ссылку, она не открывается, но если кликнуть средней кнопкой мыши, то ссылка открывается. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
 <li class="section-tiles__item" id="bx_1847241719_545">
    <div class="section-tiles__tile">
        <div class="section-tiles__label">PlusSteam</div>
        <div class="section-tiles__img-holder">
            <div class="section-tiles__img-link">
                <a href="/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/">
                <img src="/upload/tmp/300x3002no-photo.png" class="section-tiles__img-main" alt=" " data-at2x="/upload/tmp/300x3002@2xno-photo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-tiles__title-section">
            <div class="section-tiles__title">
                <a href="/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/" class="section-tiles__title-text">Серия AQUATRONIC</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section-tiles__content-section">
            <div class="section-tiles__content content-area">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
 </li>
```

Никакой JS не висит на ссылке, никакой блок не перекрывает её, палец при наведении появляется, ховер эффект тоже, но вот левый клик не работает

Comment: Не воспроизводится.

Comment: @DantheHat, в сниппете проблема не воспроизводится, поэтому делать сниппет смысла нет.

Comment: На вид работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил что бы посмотреть - будет ли проблема.

Comment: Выдвину предположение о том, что обе ваши ссылки ведут на текущую страницу и страница настолько быстро "перезагружается " из кэша, что вы не успеваете этого заметить. И было бы проще, если бы вы дали ссылку на проблемную страницу.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<li class="section-tiles__item" id="bx_1847241719_545">
   <div class="section-tiles__tile">
      <div class="section-tiles__label">PlusSteam</div>
      <div class="section-tiles__img-holder">
         <a href="/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/">
            <div class="section-tiles__img-link">
               <img src="/upload/tmp/300x3002no-photo.png" class="section-tiles__img-main" alt=" " data-at2x="/upload/tmp/300x3002@2xno-photo.png">
            </div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="section-tiles__title-section">
         <a href="/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/" class="section-tiles__title-text">
            <div class="section-tiles__title">
               Серия AQUATRONIC
            </div>
      </div>
      </a>
      <div class="section-tiles__content-section">
         <div class="section-tiles__content content-area">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не воспроизводится. Вероятно, следует проверить обработчики событий через devtools браузера и выяснить, какой именно вызывает `preventDefault`.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/188722)

Comment: @br3t, да ну? Почему же не является?

Comment: Чисто интуитивно :) По факту это же вроде рекомендация по поиску решения проблемы, а не само решение. Плюс автор настаивает на отсутствии блокирующих скриптов. Банальный клик колесиком по идее тоже не должен проходить, если тут не какой-то фантастически парноидальный prevent с  which.

Comment: @br3t, средний клик ссылки - это браузерное Открыть в новой вкладке - скрипты его вообще не получат. А то, что обработчик не висит на ссылке не означает, что выше по дереву нет обработчиков.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема возникла когда я добавил на сайт навигационное меню. Все ссылки этого меню перестали срабатывать на левую кнопку, для этого меню я прописал маленький JS и из-за этого перестало работать. Нашёл способ: в ссылку надо прописать onclick="window.open('Ваша ссылка')" 
Вот так будет выглядеть, надеюсь поможет.

Comment: <a href="/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/" onclick="window.open('/catalog/home/vodonagrevateli/gas-vodo/seriya-aquatronic/')">

Comment: Добавте информацию из комментария [прямо в ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1081353/edit). Комментаррии не являются составной частью ответа.